# How to preserve trailing 0 for a number in oracle?

Tags: oracle

Why `select to_char(32.00, 'FM999990D999') from dual` returns me `32,` ?

If I understood it fine, `FM` is supposed to keep trailing and  leading 0, isn't it?

(source : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0300__Conversion-Functions/FormatParameters.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
select to_char(32.00, '999990D999') from dual;
```

From page you've provided:

> FM    FM90.9  **Removes leading and trailing spaces from number.**

Comment: Ok yes that was a misunderstood... my bad. But is there a way to not putting random number of 0 ? I'm treating coordinates, so sometimes it could be 0.00005, sometimes 32.00. Just adding enough '9' is the trick ?

Comment: @So4ne Yes add five 9 after `D`

Comment: Ok that's a little dispapointing it can't be automatic. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: @So4ne By the way better use official Oracle documentation